# How to quickly find the controller and method that implement an API call, given the URL?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Given a particular API URL (for example, a network call that is observed in Chrome dev tools), what is the fastest/easiest way to locate the web controller and method that implements that route in a WebAPI project?

Since route attributes in a WebAPI project ultimately specify the route a controller will respond to, it is not necessarily a one-to-one convention-based mapping that would make it trivial to find the right controller and the right method on it.  I'm even open to using Roslyn or other tooling if need be.  I would like to reduce the friction when troubleshooting a web call and quick navigation to the backend implementation would go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a web call under my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool monitoring and it will show the controller and methods that implement it.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting and useful tool.  I'll be sure to check it out!